# How to call a java method by clicking a button in JSP and also pass parameter?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to pass a parameter given by user to a java method.

I have a controller class, two JSPs, an index.jsp and bresult.jsp, what I need is at the index page: The user can give an input and by an "add" button call a java method which need that parameter.

In my controller:

```
@Autowired
    public void setA(Scheduler schedulerObject) {
        this.schedulerObject = schedulerObject;
    }
```

```
@GetMapping("/")
       public String index() {
           return "index";
       }
```

```
@PostMapping("/bresult")
    public String bresult(@RequestParam("newMachineType") String newMachineType, Model model) throws InterruptedException 
        {
                        schedulerObject.loadDataBase();
            schedulerObject.createDefaultMachines();
            some other codes here...
            return "bresult";
        }
```

index.jsp:

```
<form action="bresult" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter new machine type:</td>
        <td><input id="newMachineType" name ="newMachineType"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>                      
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So in index if I want to add any new machine, after giving the type, a button would add it to a list, and if I click on submit, it will give results based on my other codes.

How can I call and pass the paramter (machine type) to my java method, but only if I click on the add button?

Answer (score 0):

You action is pointing to your method correctly

```
<form action="bresult" method="post">
@PostMapping("/bresult")
```

And your param (in html)is using the same name in your controller

```
<td><input id="newMachineType" name ="newMachineType"></td>
@RequestParam("newMachineType") String newMachineType
```

Is it not working? You can use the String normally in your controller class. Did you use @Controller in the class? Try to System.out.println(newMachineType) and look in your console to verify the value of that variable and check if is the same as you passed in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Change your post method for taking `HttpServletRequest` to get form values as parameter.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

```
@PostMapping("/bresult")
public String bresult(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws InterruptedException
{
    // ----

    String newMachineType = request.getParameter("newMachineType");
    ...
    // If more than one parameter for machine type 
    String newMachineType2 = request.getParameter("newMachineType2"); 
    String newMachineType3 = request.getParameter("newMachineType3"); 
    String newMachineType4 = request.getParameter("newMachineType4"); 
    ...

    // ----
    schedulerObject.loadDataBase();
    schedulerObject.createDefaultMachines();
    some other codes here...
    return "bresult";
}
```

For multiple and dynamic entity. You can change approach of your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $( "#addButton" ).click(function() {
        $('body > form > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').after('<td><input id="newMachineType" name ="newMachineType' + counter + '"></td>');
        counter++;
    });
});
</script>

<button id="addButton" type="button">Add new machine type</button>
<form action="bresult" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter new machine type:</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>                      
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

HTML edited for add button of new machine. So you can add how many you need.
Then submit all of it and get values from `bresult()`

Comment: Thanks, but, if I place the "add" method in "bresult" controller method it would happen only if I click on "submit" button which lead to the "bresult.jsp" which shows computing results, so the "add" button should be useable multiple times before that, and should call the required "add" method in a different controller method than "bresult", but I'm very inexperienced how to do it correctly.

Comment: So you need to hold data which added machines in somewhere, than show at "/bresult" route right ? Do you have any limit ? For example; if you enter just 5 machine, add 5 textBox right there, after the sumbition get all these data to add "bresult".

Comment: At "bresult" controller method, "schedulerObject.createDefaultMachines();" this statement creates x numbers of machines, but after that, I want to give the possibility to the user to add more machines without limits, write the type, then click on add, and the user can repeat this no matter how many time, and if it's enough, click on submit and my code will compute and results bill we shown at bresult page. The createDefaultMachines() should be different controller method I guess which should be activated also by clicking a button.

Comment: Editing answer for multiple input values of it.